# How to repeat different numeric values into a dataframe in python (similar to rep() in R)

Tags: python, repeat, rep

I would like to make a dataframe in python with two values (red and yellow) that repeat different quantities (1599 and 4898). The column should first have red 1599 times following yellow 4898 times.

In R it would look like:

```
colors <- c(rep("Red",1599),rep("Yellow",4898))
```

How do I make the same exact column in python?

Comment: `pd.Series(['Red']*1599 + ['Yellow']*4898)`. `list` elements can be multiplied. Or `pd.Series(['Red','Yellow']).repeat([1599, 4898])`, rows can be repeated.

Comment: Your question is hard to answer, because the desired result could be a `pd.DateFrame`, a `pd.Series`, a `np.array` or a python `list`, but not a 'column'. Please clarify what you expect as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your R code, you did not use numerical values to encode textual values of red and yellow, so I still use string here.

This is what comes to my mind:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

red_values = np.array(['red'] * 1599)
red_part = pd.DataFrame(red_values)
yellow_values = np.array(['yelllow'] * 4898)
yellow_part = pd.DataFrame(yellow_values)
my_dataframe = pd.concat([red_part, yellow_part], axis=0)
```

The result will be like:

[image]